# Python Neural Network Prediction

Tags: neural-network

I am working on a project , I have two various numbers :

1- First number maximum value is 1500 and minimum is 200.

2- Second number maximum value is 200 and minimum is 10.

3- I want to create neural network , adding samples and train the network to predict the last number, for example :

```
900,67 equals 87
870,99 equals 100
1000,50 equals ?
```

What's type of neural networks can work with my project?

Comment: Can you provide code to generate the data, or a sample dataset? Since you mentioned "number",I think this a regression problem, so you can start with a "feed forward network for regression". Give it a try and post your Python code then I'm sure we can help!

Comment: Data generated by two sensors . I will try and post the code

Answer (score 0):

To this example, you input two values and get one.

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

MIN = np.random.rand(100)*500
MAX = np.random.rand(100)*500 + 500
x = np.concatenate((MIN.reshape(-1,1),MAX.reshape(-1,1)),axis = 1)
y = np.sin(x[:,0])*500 + np.cos(x[:,1])*500

x_max = x.max()
y_max = y.max()
x = x/x_max
y = (y-y.min())/(y_max-y.min())
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(200,input_dim = 2, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation = 'relu'))
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.6, beta_2=0.97, amsgrad=False)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer=opt , metrics=['mse'])
model.fit(x, y, epochs=10000, batch_size=2)

y_hat = model.predict(x)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.plot(y)
plt.plot(y_hat.reshape(-1))
```

This is the result:

[image]

You will need to make pre and post processing, normalizing inputs and reescaling outputs from the neural network. This is the input:

[image]

use example:

```
In [10]: model.predict(np.array([0.234,0.567]).reshape(-1,2))
Out[10]: array([[0.61975896]], dtype=float32)
```